# Returning 'Error' in a While Loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm new to python and was hoping if someone could help me with this problem.

Here's The code:

```
uninput1=input('> ')
    while True:
        if 'existing' in uninput1 or 'existing file' in uninput1:
            print ('Please enter the directory of your file.')
            dirfile=input('> ')
            print (space)
            time.sleep(1)
            print ('Now enter the name of your file.')
            nmfile=input('> ')
            print (space)
            time.sleep(1)
            txtmod.existing(dirfile, nmfile)

        elif 'new' in uninput1 or 'create' in uninput1:
            print ('Please enter the directory where you want to create your file.')
            dirfile=input('> ')
            print (space)
            time.sleep(1)
            print ('Now enter the name you want to give to your file.')
            nmfile=input('> ')
            print (space)
            time.sleep(1)
            txtmod.newfile(dirfile, nmfile)


        else:
            print ('Error! Please Try again')
```

What i'm trying to do is to return an error when the user types a certain thing and restart the loop.But what happens is that instead of restarting the loop it just displays my 'error' forever. Can anyone help?

I don't know if this makes sense or not but i hope it does to someone.

Comment: BTW, `'existing' in uninput1 or 'existing file' in uninput1` can be replaced by `'existing' in uninput1`, since `'existing file' in uninput1` will never be true if `'existing' in uninput1` is false.

Comment: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/953482) may be of interest to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at where your input is:

```
uninput1=input('> ')
while True:
    ...
```

As you can see, your input is *outside* the loop - so, when the loop gets repeated, it never gets activated. The solution is simply to move it inside the loop:

```
while True:
    uninput1=input('> ')
    if ...
    ...
```